# Aurelia won't load template without <require> while using webpack

Tags: webpack, aurelia

I'm loading template dynamically in aurelia and while using webpack a view won't load unless added as `<require from="..."></require>`. When using aurelia-cli this was not necessary. Why? Does this have anything to do with how webpack loads modules?

I'm using aurelia with asp.net core template in Visual Studio 2017 generate by `dotnet new aurelia` as per https://github.com/EisenbergEffect/aspnetcore-aurelia-build-2017

```
<!-- this part was not required when using cli -->
<require from="../empty-report/empty-report"></require>

<compose id="printcontent" view-model="../${report.type}-report/${report.type}-report" model.bind="report"></compose>
```

my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { AureliaPlugin } = require('aurelia-webpack-plugin');
const bundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';

module.exports = (env) => {
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    return [{
        stats: { modules: false },
        entry: { 'app': 'aurelia-bootstrapper' },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
            modules: ['ClientApp', 'node_modules'],
        },
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(bundleOutputDir),
            publicPath: '/dist/',
            filename: '[name].js'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.ts$/i, include: /ClientApp/, use: 'ts-loader?silent=true' },
                { test: /\.html$/i, use: 'html-loader' },
                { test: /\.css$/i, use: isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({ IS_DEV_BUILD: JSON.stringify(isDevBuild) }),
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
            }),
            new AureliaPlugin({ aureliaApp: 'boot' })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(bundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]')  // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
        ])
    }];
}
```

UPDATE #1

When edited bootstrapper to allow for resources, webpack builds, but loading the site I'll get an error

boot.ts

```
import 'isomorphic-fetch';
import { Aurelia, PLATFORM } from 'aurelia-framework';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap';
declare const IS_DEV_BUILD: boolean; // The value is supplied by Webpack during the build

export function configure(aurelia: Aurelia) {
    aurelia.use
        .standardConfiguration()
        .feature(PLATFORM.moduleName('resources'));// /index makes no difference

    //aurelia.use.plugin('aurelia-table');
    //aurelia.use.plugin('aurelia-chart');

    if (IS_DEV_BUILD) {
        aurelia.use.developmentLogging();
    }

    aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName('app/components/app/app')));
}
```

error:

```
aurelia-loader-webpack.js:187 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unable to find module with ID: resources/index
    at WebpackLoader.<anonymous> (aurelia-loader-webpack.js:187)
    at step (aurelia-loader-webpack.js:36)
    at Object.next (aurelia-loader-webpack.js:17)
    at aurelia-loader-webpack.js:11
    at Promise (<anonymous>)
    at 146.__awaiter (aurelia-loader-webpack.js:7)
    at WebpackLoader.146.WebpackLoader._import (aurelia-loader-webpack.js:152)
    at WebpackLoader.<anonymous> (aurelia-loader-webpack.js:252)
    at step (aurelia-loader-webpack.js:36)
    at Object.next (aurelia-loader-webpack.js:17)
```

UPDATE #2:

I can confirm that the issue was the missing `.feature('resources')` or `.feature(PLATFORM.moduleName('resources'))`, but even when adding index.ts (as advised here: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/app-configuration-and-startup/6) I am not able to load features this way

I have organised my app as per above instructions on Aurelia page, but I still get the same error `Error: Unable to find module with ID: resources/index`. I have placed all my elements/components in resources folder and added index.ts in the same folder.

Comment: as far as I know all components not assigned as global resources (e.g. with `.globalResources('./empty-report/empty-report');`) will need to use a `require` to bring them into context; this was intentionally designed in order to avoid name clashing and improve clarity e.g. compared to other frameworks like angularjs

Comment: that make sense, but why did it work while using cli? in CLI bootstrapper I've had aurelia.use.feature('resources') Is this why it worked?

Comment: bingo, yes `aurelia.use.feature('...')` is just like declaring all components inside as global resources - see [this](http://drdwilcox.blogspot.ro/2015/12/aurelia-making-custom-element-global.html)

Comment: that is slightly clearer not, but still with a bit of error. I have updated the issue.

Comment: that's because the `.feature` approach expects to have an `index` inside the folder you're registering - `aurelia-cli` approach was probably doing this for you - now you must manually add this index in resources - a file that collects all your resources like this `export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.globalResources('./empty-report/empty-report')`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the new aurelia webpack plugin/setup? If yes then you should load features like this `aurelia.use.feature(PLATFORM.moduleName('my-feature/index');`

Same goes for `moduleId` fields on routes.

More info here https://github.com/jods4/aurelia-webpack-build/wiki/Debugging-missing-modules

Comment: even with the PLATFORM.modulename, still the same error

Comment: Does it help if you add a ./ to the start of the path ? I was doing the same here with custom bindingBehaviours and if I did not use the ./ to start the path webpack would spit.